# How to scrape websites in Node-red

Tags: web-scraping, node-red

I need to scrape a website in Node-red, but I'm not sure about how I should do it.

I know how to scrape websites in Google Spreadsheets, but I don't know how to do the same with the html node in node-red.

This it what I use in Google Spreadsheets:

`=index(importxml("https://www.website.dom";"//h2[@class='item-title']");1)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `HTTP Request` node to get the content of a page, followed by the `HTML` node to extract the parts you are interested in.

[image]

The cookbook includes an example recipe for this here: https://cookbook.nodered.org/http/simple-get-request